# Angular FormArray validation error with ReactiveFormModule

Tags: angular, angular8

```
this.billingForm = this.fb.group({
      "fullname": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S'), Validators.minLength(3)]],
      "address1": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')]],
      "address2": [null, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')],
      "city": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')]],
      "state": [null, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')],
      "zipcode": [null, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')],
      "country": [null, Validators.required],
      "taxId": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')]],
      "contacts": this.fb.array([this.contactDetail()], [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')])      
    });
```

The Validators.pattern('.*\S') is not working with form array and works for other control.

Comment: You should be be adding `Validators.pattern('.*\S')` to the `formControl` within `this.contactDetail()` and not the `formArray as a whole.

Comment: `contactDetail(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      "emailAddress": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      "phone": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')]],
      "contactPerson": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*\\S')]]
    });
  }`                                                                                                                                                                          I have also added here but its not work?